# Java equity options pricing library

Tags: java, finance

I have price data for some US equities and corresponding options (puts and calls).  I'm looking for a Java library to help derive some theoretical greeks (delta, gamma, etc.)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with [jqantlib](http://www.jquantlib.org/sites/jquantlib/apidocs/current/index.html)